# copy a single file to many folders which contain as condition another single file

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I have many folders on my hard disk which contain the file "output.txt".

Now I want to copy in each of this folders the same single file "info.txt".

How can I do that with the command shell of windows (or powershell)?

E.g:

```
Folder 1: d:\tmp\tmp1\output.txt
Folder 2: d:\tmp\tmp1\tmp2\output.txt
Folder 3: d:\tmp\tmp3\output.txt
...
```

I want copy `info.txt` (e.g. from `d:\info.txt`) to:

```
Folder 1: d:\tmp\tmp1\info.txt
Folder 2: d:\tmp\tmp1\tmp2\info.txt
Folder 3: d:\tmp\tmp3\info.txt
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for /f "delims=" %x in ('dir /b /s d:\tmp\output.txt') do copy d:\info.txt "%~dpx"
```

In .BAT file double both percent chars.

Comment: Thank you. If I changed the file `info.txt` I had to overwrite it in each folder by using `... copy /Y ...`

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
gci "d:\tmp\*\output.txt" -recurse | %{copy-item 'd:\info.txt' $_.PSParentPath}
```

Keith

Comment: I would appreciate constructive criticism from anyone taking the time to down-vote my reply.